# How to store App in SDcard

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am very new to android development.... i have created an app and want to store it in my android mobile. But normally all apps gets stored in mobile memory and it now shows no space so i want to store it in my SD card. Pls get me a solution for this issue....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the dev. guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html):
Add this to your manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

Note that as @Vinayak.B mentions in the comments, and as the guide says, this is available

> "Beginning with API Level 8"

Comment: This is allowed only with the Android versions greater than Froyo (2.2 ).